# Joining tables based on the maximum id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have found three questions which all seem to ask a *similar* question:

[Getting max value from rows and joining to another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473718/getting-max-value-from-rows-and-joining-to-another-table)

[Select only rows by join tables max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694094/select-only-rows-by-join-tables-max-value/18694271)

[Joining tables based on the maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863606/joining-tables-based-on-the-maximum-value/1863645)

But I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how exactly to join tables keeping only the maximum row of one of the tables when the maximum is in the id or index field itself.

I am looking for an answers that only require joins because this will allow the solution to work in a tool which generates queries for which it is easy to get it to generate the corresponding joins, although sub-queries are probably doable as well with a bit more effort.  I found the answer below to be of particular interest:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.id, b.filename, a1.name
FROM a a1
JOIN b
  ON b.id = a1.id
LEFT JOIN a a2
  ON a2.id = a1.id
  AND a2.rank > a1.rank
WHERE a2.id IS NULL
```

However, in my case the ranking column is also the index, e.g. "id".  I cannot compare for equality and greater than at the same time, because they will never be true at the same time!

Also, potentially complicating the situation is that a typical query in which I have need of this may join several tables (3-5 is not uncommon).  So as a simplified example of my query:

```
SELECT
    table1.field1, table1.field2, table1.field3,
    table2.field1, table2.field2, table2.field3,
    table3.field1, table3.field2, table3.field3,
    table4.field1, table4.field2, table4.field3
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON
    table1.field1 = table2.field1
    AND table1.field2 = table2.field2
    AND table2.field3 < 0
INNER JOIN table3 ON
    table2.field1 = table3.field1
    AND table2.field4 = table3.field4
INNER JOIN table4 ON
    table1.field1 = table4.field1
    AND table1.field2 = table4.field2
```

And what I want to do is to eliminate duplicates in table3 by only getting the row with the maximum id (e.g. MAX(table3.id)) for each unique combination of all the other fields.  That is to say, the above query is returning something like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+---------+
| table1| table2| table4|table3   |
+-------+-------+-------+---------+
|  A    |   A   |   A   | 1,...   |
|  A    |   A   |   A   | 2,...   |
|  A    |   A   |   A   | 3,...   |
|  A    |   A   |   A   | MAX2,...|
|  B    |   B   |   B   | 1,...   |
|  B    |   B   |   B   | 2,...   |
|  B    |   B   |   B   | 3,...   |
|  B    |   B   |   B   | MAX2,...|
+-------+-------+-------+---------+
```

(I'm just using A and B to denote that I'm talking about all the same values for the fields in table1, table2, and table4 for a particular set of rows.)

and I want to reduce it to this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+---------+
| table1| table2| table4|table3   |
+-------+-------+-------+---------+
|  A    |   A   |   A   | MAX1,...|
|  B    |   B   |   B   | MAX2,...|
+-------+-------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: How about `SELECT table1.id, MAX(table3.field3) FROM (<query from above>) GROUP BY table1.id` ?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError `SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2, table1.field3, table2.field1, table2.field2, table2.field3, table3.field1, table3.field2, table3.field3, table4.field1, table4.field2, table4.field3 table1.id, MAX(table3.field3) FROM (<query from above>) GROUP BY table1.id` ?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: @Michael I think it should be SELECT table1.columns, table2.columns, table4.columns, MAX(table3.columns) and GROUP BY table1.columns, table2.columns, table4.columns.  If you don't aggregate all columns from table3 then those should be put to the GROUP BY

Comment: @DávidLaczkó My understanding was that some databases don't guarantee that MAX and GROUP BY will play well together to return data from the same row.  For instance, if table 3 has "3, A, RED", "4, B, BLUE", "5, C, WHITE" for id, field1 and field2, then MAX(id) will return 5 but the field1 and field2 values aren't guaranteed to be "C" and "WHITE"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a derived table to reduce the matching rows in `TABLE3` to one per group. Another method would use a window function but you asked for a `JOIN` only

```
SELECT
    table1.field1, table1.field2, table1.field3,
    table2.field1, table2.field2, table2.field3,
    table3.field1, table3.field2, table3.field3,
    table4.field1, table4.field2, table4.field3
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON
    table1.field1 = table2.field1
    AND table1.field2 = table2.field2
    AND table2.field3 < 0
INNER JOIN table3 ON
    table2.field1 = table3.field1
    AND table2.field4 = table3.field4

--here is the added derived table. Change column names as needed
INNER JOIN (select UID, ID = max(ID) from Table3 group by UID) x
    on x.UID = table3.UID and x.mx = table3.ID

INNER JOIN table4 ON
    table1.field1 = table4.field1
    AND table1.field2 = table4.field2
```

Or, perhaps... something like below. It really depends on your schema and that's hard to understand with the sample data.

```
INNER JOIN (select field1, field4, mx = max(ID) from Table3 group by field1, field4) x
    on x.field1 = table3.field1 and x.field4 = table3.field4 and x.mx = table3.ID
```

Here is an example. You'll notice that the last three column pairs are identical. You only want the last one, which is the max(id) for that grouping. What ever makes a row unique in relation to the rest of your data (not your primary key, but what you are joining with) is what you'd want to include int he derived table and join condition.

```
declare @table table (id int identity(1,1), f1 char(1), f2 char(1))
insert into @table
values
('a','b'),
('a','c'),
('a','a'),
('b','b'),
('b','b'),
('b','b')

select * from @table

select t1.*
from @table t1
inner join 
    (select f1, f2, mx = max(id) from @table group by f1, f2) t2 on
    t1.f1 = t2.f1
    and t1.f2 = t2.f2
    and t1.id = t2.mx
```

Comment: Sorry, a bit confused... I think UID is the id field of the table and ID is the max, so should that be `ID=max(UID)`, and  `from Table3 group by UID`?

Comment: UID was a poor name choice probably. So, UID here would be a foreign key (most likely to your other tables. So, either field1 or field4... or both if you need them. the ID would be the column where you want the max. If you want the max(ID) for each field1 / field4 pair, then just replace UID with these two columns and group by them and add them to the join clause (i'll add a snippet at the bottom in an edit)

Comment: also i had table2 in the derived table, it was supposed to be table3. You are doing a self inner join is the point to limit the rows. and x.id should have been x.mx since that is what i aliased it as.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't really document the schema, I'm trying to solve the general case as I've got several queries I'm trying to fix, so you can just assume there is an "id" field which is the index (e.g. INTEGER PRIMARY KEY or whatever) and arbitrary numbered fields "field1", "field2" etc. up to however many fields there are for every table.  If I'm understanding the select in the self-join should (just) include all the fields the previous table was joined on?

Comment: Ok, so I modified the derived table to self-join on all the field "table3" was previous joined on and... i'm now getting the expected number of rows.  Looks good, just need to do some final verification and I'll accept.